# TRACEBACK Python Die Game

Tags: python, python-3.4, traceback

I am writing a die simulation game to better understand the basics of python, but...
It throws up a Traceback Error.
It would be greatly appreciated if you could assist me in fixing this

```
import random


def DiceSize():
    DieSize= int(input("""Please pick a dice size,
4 Sides
6 Sides
12 Sides"""))
    if not (DieSize == 4 or DieSize == 6 or DieSize == 12):
        print("Thats not right!")
        DiceSize()
    else:
        print("You have picked %i" % DieSize)
        RollDice()

def RollDice():
    if DieSize == 4:
        min = 1
        max = 4
        print("ROLLING")
        print (random.randint(min, max))
        RollAgain()
    elif DieSize == 6:
        min = 1
        max = 6
        print("ROLLING")
        print(random.randint(min, max))
        RollAgain()
    else:
        min = 1
        max = 12
        print("ROLLING")
        print(random.randint(min, max))
        RollAgain()

def RollAgain():
    roll_again = input("Do you want to roll again: ").lower()

    if roll_again == "y":
              DiceSize()
    else:
              print()

DiceSize()
```

Comment: You need to close all of the ( that you open. And in the future, include a traceback.

Comment: How would I add a Traceback?

Comment: `print("You have picked %i" % DieSize)` is a cleaner way to string concat. not really that big of a deal, but something you should check out

Comment: Traceback is the error that your script returns when you try to run it.  `Traceback (most recent call last):`...

Comment: How would I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is that you arent passing the diesize

```
    RollDice(DieSize)

def RollDice(DieSize):
```

Comment: That has worked now, but since im new to Python could you please explain to me why this is necessary?

Comment: Because you are passing a parameter from one method to another, the DieSize is set in DiceSize() but RollDice() has no concept of that variable with out having it passed to it